# appwrite web sdk with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, appwrite

I am using [demo-todo-with-react](https://github.com/appwrite/demo-todo-with-react) with typescript. For [api.js](https://github.com/appwrite/demo-todo-with-react/blob/main/src/api/api.js) creating api.tsx it gives me error on api.sdk={database,account} "Type '{database: Database; account: Account;}' is not assignable to type 'null' "

```
let api = {
  sdk: null,

  provider: () => {
    if (api.sdk) {
      return api.sdk;
    }
    let appwrite = new Appwrite();
    appwrite.setEndpoint(Server.endpoint).setProject(Server.project);
    const account = new Account(appwrite);
    const database = new Databases(appwrite);

    api.sdk = { database, account };
    return api.sdk;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a custom type for the `api` object.
In your case it would be something like this.

```js
interface AnyApi {
 sdk: null | any;
 provider: () => any;
}


let api: AnyApi = {
...
}
```

This would work.

If you want to go fowreder add a template like this.

```js
interface AnyApi<T> {
 sdk: null | T;
 provider: () => T;
}

interface AppWriteSdk {
 database: Database;
 account: Account;
}

let api: AnyApi<AppWriteSdk>= {
...
}
```